# xgboost: give more importance to recent samples

Tags: xgboost, weighted-data

Is there a way to add more importance to points which are more recent when analyzing data with xgboost?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try building multiple xgboost models, with some of them being limited to more recent data, then weighting those results together.  Another idea would be to make a customized evaluation metric that penalizes recent points more heavily which would give them more importance.

Comment: The OP can simply give higher sample weights to more recent observations. Most packages allow this, [as does xgboost.](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit)

Answer (score 43):

Just add weights based on your time labels to your xgb.DMatrix.
The following example is written in R but the same principle applies to xgboost on Python or Julia.

```
data <- data.frame(feature = rep(5, 5),
                   year = seq(2011, 2015), 
                   target = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
weightsData <- 1 + (data$year - max(data$year)) * 5 * 0.01

#Now create the xgboost matrix with your data and weights
xgbMatrix <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(data$feature), 
                         label = data$target, 
                         weight = weightsData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - its really helpful to see a coded example. How does the magnitude of the weighting function coefficients affect the model? I looked through xgboost docs, but I can't find information about the significance of these numerical values.

Comment: didn't know this trick, nice. there's a little tidbit in the xgboost doc under the function `setinfo()`, though its not very descriptive

Answer (score 23):

On Python you have a nice scikit-learn wrapper, so you can write just like this:

```
import xgboost as xgb
exgb_classifier = xgb.XGBClassifier()
exgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weights_data)
```

More information you can receive from this:
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit

Comment: Wish for R caret had this built in too..

Comment: that should be `xgb.XGBClassifier()` in the second line of code but stackexchange does not allow edits of less than six characters...