# Unbalanced multiclass data with XGBoost

Tags: classification, xgboost, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance

I have 3 classes with this distribution:

```
Class 0: 0.1169
Class 1: 0.7668
Class 2: 0.1163
```

And I am using `xgboost` for classification. I know that there is a parameter called `scale_pos_weight`.

But how is it handled for 'multiclass' case, and how can I properly set it?

Comment: what is the dataset problem?   I want to try the weight class to see if the classifier can perform well using it.  I have a similiar problem while trying to predict equipment failure.  the classes are 'error1', 'error4', 'error5', 'No Error', 'error2', 'error3' where No Error is 95% of the data.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`scale_pos_weight` is used for binary classification as you stated. It is a more generalized solution to handle imbalanced classes. A good approach when assigning a value to `scale_pos_weight` is:

```
sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances)
```

For your specific case, there is another option in order to weight individual data points and take their weights into account while working with the booster, and let the optimization happen regarding their weights so that each point is represented equally. You just need to simply use:

```
xgboost.DMatrix(..., weight = *weight array for individual weights*)
```

You can define the weights as you like and by doing so, you can even handle imbalances within classes as well as imbalances across different classes.

Comment: > A good approach when assigning a value to scale_pos_weight is: sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances)

Comment: I see this advice everywhere and it make sense to assign a higher weight to the less represented class. However I have a hard time finding a source discussing this exact value. I get the intuition behind that specific value (make the sample balanced) but I suspect there is a variance trade-off somewhere, that would make you want consider lower weight.

Comment: Personally @Kerem it is still unclear to me if the positive instances are the majority or the minority classes. Do we assume that always positive=majority and negative=minority and hence sum(negative instances)/sum(positive instances)=sum(minority)/sum(majority)?

Comment: This is attempt to clarify the doubt raised by @Outcast.

Effectively scale_pos_weight scales the error of positive cases. if the positive cases are majority in then value of scale_pos_weight < 1 and hence positive case errors will be scaled down. 
However if positive cases are minority then scale_pos_weight > 1 and hence positive case errors will be scaled up. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: @Kerem T How can you use it inside a pipeline?

Answer (score 21):

[This answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18823/67328) by @KeremT is correct. I provide an example for those who still have problems with the exact implementation.

`weight` parameter in XGBoost is per instance not per class. Therefore, we need to assign the weight of each class to its instances, which is the same thing.

For example, if we have three imbalanced classes with ratios

```
class A = 10%
class B = 30%
class C = 60%
```

Their weights would be (dividing the smallest class by others)

```
class A = 1.000
class B = 0.333
class C = 0.167
```

Then, if training data is

```
index   class
0       A
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       B
```

we build the `weight` vector as follows:

```
index   class    weight
0       A        1.000
1       A        1.000
2       B        0.333
3       C        0.167
4       B        0.333
```

Comment: thanks for this, how does this affect the probability output for xgboost? i.e. when we come to optimize the loss function does the weight act on the optimizartion of the loss?

Comment: This example is a bit misleading, if you feed this data now as input to your classifier then you will get a 100% accuracy since you have already told the model what the actual classes are

Comment: @Guarav, not at all correct.  The weights are not features for the model.  They influence the gradients or error function only.

Answer (score 18):

**For sklearn version < 0.19**

Just assign each entry of your train data its class weight. First get the class weights with `class_weight.compute_class_weight` of sklearn then assign each row of the train data its appropriate weight.

I assume here that the train data has the column `class` containing the class number. I assumed also that there are `nb_classes` that are from 1 to `nb_classes`.

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
classes_weights = list(class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                             np.unique(train_df['class']),
                                             train_df['class']))

weights = np.ones(y_train.shape[0], dtype = 'float')
for i, val in enumerate(y_train):
    weights[i] = classes_weights[val-1]

xgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights)
```

**Update for sklearn version >= 0.19**

There is simpler solution

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
classes_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight(
    class_weight='balanced',
    y=train_df['class']
)

xgb_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight=classes_weights)
```

Comment: You can use now simply `compute_sample_weight('balanced', y)` from `sklearn.utils`

Comment: What about the use inside a Pipeline?

Answer (score 6):

Everyone stumbles upon this question when dealing with unbalanced multiclass classification problem using XGBoost in R. I did too!

I was looking for an example to better understand how to apply it. Invested almost an hour to find the link mentioned below. For all those who are looking for an example, [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9493/37156) goes.

Thanks [wacax](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/13023/wacax)

Comment: Can you add some description of what the link is? Otherwise this is a link-only answer. Your bottom line is `xgb.DMatrix(..., weight)` has an instance-specific (not per-class) `weight` argument, and you can tweak it per-instance.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter ***scale_pos_weight*** works for two classes (binary classification).

The parameter ***weight*** goes into the xgb.DMatrix function can be used for three or more classes. The weights can be computed like this:

```
weights = total_samples / (n_classes * class_samples * 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using scale_pos_weight and weights in case of binary classification will bring comparable result.