# How to set weights in multi-class classification in xgboost for imbalanced data?

Tags: xgboost, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance

From [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost/18823), I know you can set `scale_pos_weight` for an imbalanced dataset.  However, for the multi-classification problem in the imbalanced dataset, I don't quite understand how to set the weight parameter in `dmatrix`.

How can I use XGBoost for an imbalanced dataset in a multi-classification problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `scale_pos_weight` works for two classes (binary classification). `weight` can be used for three or more classes. The parameter goes into the `xgb.DMatrix` function and must contain one value for each observation.

Example:

```
library(xgboost)
data(iris)

# We'll predict Species
label = as.integer(iris$Species)-1
iris$Species = NULL

# Split the data for training and testing (75/25 split)
n = nrow(iris)
train.index = sample(n,floor(0.75*n))

# For example, pick a weight of 1.5 for label "0", 1.0 for the other Species
weights = sapply(label[train.index], function(x) {ifelse(x == 0, 1.5, 1.0)})

# Train the data using weights
xgb.train = xgb.DMatrix(data=as.matrix(iris[train.index,]), label=label[train.index], weight = weights)
```

A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983565/how-is-the-parameter-weight-dmatrix-used-in-the-gradient-boosting-procedure).