# XGboost and regularization

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

Does the `XGBClassifier` method utilizes the two regularization terms `reg_alpha` and `reg_lambda`, or are they redundant and only utilized in the regression method (i.e., `XGBRegressor`)?

I think that some hyperparameters in XGBoost could have no effect on specific methods (e.g., `scale_pos_weight` in `XGBRegressor`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XGB uses the two kinds of regularization in both classification and regression; each leaf is a continuous score, these scores added together for the final prediction (of log-odds in the classification case), so penalizing the weights makes sense in either setting.
See also [L1 & L2 Regularization in Light GBM](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/57255/55122)

But yes, some hyperparameters (`scale_pos_weight`) seem to be vestigial:
[What does xgb's scale_pos_weight parameter do for regression?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/25948/55122)
https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/scale-pos-weight-for-regression/218/10