# Adjust class weights due to class imbalance and class importance Multi class classification XGBoost

Tags: python, classification, xgboost, multiclass-classification, class-imbalance

With respect to this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost/18823#18823) and the answer given by @Esmailian, Would anyone be able to let me know **if** Class B has a **higher** importance or the positive class ( i.e. it needs to have a higher predicted accuracy not necessarily at the expense of other classes). How should we readjust the weights of the classes. I tried to increase the weight of class in importance (Class B) but the accuracy of it reduced.

Thank you

Michael

Comment: You should provide us with a bit of detail imho.