# XGBoost: How to obtain scale_pos_weight for multi classes?

Tags: machine-learning, weighted-data

I know there is a similar Qn at [Unbalanced multiclass data with XGBoost](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost).

1. But I don't understand the reply provided by @Esmailian. What is the actual formula to obtain 1, 0.333 and 0.167?

```
For example, if we have three imbalanced classes with ratios

class A = 10%
class B = 30%
class C = 60%

Their weights would be (dividing the smallest class by others)

class A = 1.000
class B = 0.333
class C = 0.167
```

2. Will I obtain the same values with

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
classes_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight(
    class_weight='balanced',
    y=train_df['class']
)
```

Comment: The values are calculated by dividing the percentage for the smallest class by the percentage for the specific class, so `% class A / % class A`, `% class A / % class B`, and `% class A / % class A`. This would give `10% / 10% = 1`, `10% / 30% = 1/3`, and `10% / 60% = 1/6`.