# XGBoost in Python: How do I input the scale_pos_weight for multi-classes?

Tags: xgboost, multiclass-classification

I have 3 classes and my weights are
Class 1: 1
Class 2: 0.333
Class 3: 0.167

How do I input them into the scale_pos_weight parameter?

I know for a binary classification, we input it like below:

```
model = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=99)
```

Comment: You don't, as the `scale_pos_weight` arugment is meant for binary classification instead of multi-class classification. You can however use the `weight` argument to specify a column to use to weigh each observation, see also the answers to [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16342/75157).

Comment: @Oxbowerce: Ok. But from the linked question. It is still not stated clearly how I should specify the inputs for the sample_weight.  Should I input as a dictionary? sample_weight={1:1,2:0.333, 3:0.167}?

Comment: You can either use the `xgboost.DMatrix` with the `weight` argument, where each observation (not just each class) needs a weight, as seen in the first answer. The second option would be to use the `weight` argument directly in `XGBClassifier`, in this case you also have to have a weight for each observation as shown in the second answer.